# How do I find child level element without finding grandchild element with querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

Starting from `<ul id="tree_view">`

```
<ul id="tree_view">
   <li>
      <span class="box">Node 1</span>
      <!-- recursive template -->
      <ul>
         <li class="nested">
            <span class="box">Leaf 1</span>
            <!-- recursive template -->
            <ul>
               <li class="nested">
                  <span class="non-box">Leaf 1-1</span>
                  <!-- recursive template -->
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="nested">
            <span class="non-box">Leaf 2</span>
            <!-- recursive template -->
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span class="box">Node 2</span>
      <!-- recursive template -->
      <ul>
         <li class="nested">
            <span class="non-box">Leaf 3</span>
            <!-- recursive template -->
         </li>
         <li class="nested">
            <span class="non-box">Leaf 4</span>
            <!-- recursive template -->
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to locate `<li class="nested">` that containers "Leaf 1" and "Leaf 2", but exclude the one containers "Leaf 1-1". Any suggestion?

I tried multiple ways, it always find all child and grandchild element with matching class .nested. I tried: `* > * > * > .nested`.

I found the solution, using "Node 1" as sample:

```js
var boxValue = "Node 1";    

const elements = this.parentElement.querySelectorAll("* > * > .nested");
       
elements.forEach(element => {

    const parentBox = element.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".box");


    if (parentBox.textContent == boxValue) {
        //found!!
    }

});
```

Comment: You always want just the first level, immediately below `class="box"`?

Comment: In that case it's `.box > .nested`

Comment: Possibly:  `#tree_view > li > .box + ul > .nested` as .nested is a li and .box is a span so `.box>.nested` would not find anything.  This would include `node 1` nested and `nod 2` nested - if you only want node1 then add an `:nth-child(0)` to get first.   It would be helpful if your sample HTML indicated which ones you want to find and which ones you don't.

Comment: Thanks for your guys input, I found it too difficult to do search and find in one round, so what I choose to do is still find all the class "nested", then loop through to check their parent node. I'll put code I did so it could help other people in my situation. If you guys have some kind of one shot way to find code, it will be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one posted any further solutions, I'll conclude this:

```
var boxValue = "Node 1";    

const elements = this.parentElement.querySelectorAll("* > * > .nested");
       
elements.forEach(element => {

    const parentBox = element.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".box");


    if (parentBox.textContent == boxValue) {
        //found!!
    }

});
```